# Why textvariable tkinter doent write my file,

Tags: python, tkinter

I am doing a small script that reads from a file and shows on the screen what you have read, if the file is modified, the Label is modified. Well, the application works perfectly for me as a script, but when I launch it as a thread in my main program, it works fine, but the labels do not write them.
Do you know what it could be? Thank you

```
import _thread
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

def AccionRecomendada(name, read):
    fin = False
    while not fin:
        archivo = open(name,"r")
        lineas = archivo.readlines()
        if len(lineas) > 1:
            recomendada = lineas[-2].replace("\n","")
        elif len(lineas) == 1:
            recomendada = lineas[0]
        else:
            recomendada = "Esperando"
        read.set(recomendada)
        sleep(0.1)


def AccionRead(name, read, dato):
    fin = False
    while not fin:
        archivo = open(name,"r")
        lineas = archivo.readlines()
        if len(lineas) > 1:
            estrategia = lineas[:-2]
            for i in range(len(estrategia)):
                estrategia[i] = estrategia[i].replace("\n","")
            temp = estrategia[dato].split(" ")
            if len(temp) >1:
                cadena1 = f"{temp[0].ljust(0)}"
                cadena2 = f"{temp[1].rjust(32)}"
                cadena = cadena1 + cadena2
            elif len(temp[0]) == 0:
                cadena = ""
            else:
                cadena = ""
        else:
            cadena = ""
        read.set(cadena)
        #print(name, cadena)
        sleep(0.1)     

def EstrategiaGUI(name, mesa):
# ----------------------------Creamos GUI para cargar la imagen----------------     
    root = Tk()
# ----------------------------Atributos siempre encima-------------------------
    root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
# --------------------------------Título----------------------------------------
    root.title(mesa)
# -----------------------------Variables----------------------------------------
    readA=StringVar()
    readB=StringVar()
    readC=StringVar()
    readD=StringVar()
    readE=StringVar()
    readF=StringVar()
    readG=StringVar()
    readH=StringVar()


    readA.set(_thread.start_new_thread(AccionRecomendada,(name, readA)))
    readB.set(_thread.start_new_thread(AccionRead,(name, readB, 0)))
    readC.set(_thread.start_new_thread(AccionRead,(name, readC, 1)))
    readD.set(_thread.start_new_thread(AccionRead,(name, readD, 2)))
    readE.set(_thread.start_new_thread(AccionRead,(name, readE, 3)))
    readF.set(_thread.start_new_thread(AccionRead,(name, readF, 4)))
    readG.set(_thread.start_new_thread(AccionRead,(name, readG, 5)))
# ------------------------------- Frames----------------------------------------
# --------------------------------Labels----------------------------------------
    miFrame = Frame(root)
    miFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
    miFrame.config(bd = 2)
    miFrame.config(relief = "groove")
# --------------------------------miFrame--------------------------------------
    LabelA=Label(miFrame, textvariable=readA)
    LabelA.grid(row=0,column=0, columnspan = 2)
    LabelA.config(anchor="center",background="#45B39D",justify="center",width="20",height="1",fg="black",
    cursor="hand2",font=("helvetica", "14", "bold"))

    LabelB=Label(miFrame, textvariable=readB)
    LabelB.grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan = 2)
    LabelB.config(anchor="w",background="#F1948A",justify="center",width="20",height="1",fg="black",
    cursor="hand2",font=("helvetica", "14", "bold"))

    LabelC=Label(miFrame, textvariable=readC)
    LabelC.grid(row=2,column=0, columnspan = 2)
    LabelC.config(anchor="w",background="#F1948A",justify="center",width="20",height="1",fg="black",
    cursor="hand2",font=("helvetica", "14", "bold"))

    LabelD=Label(miFrame, textvariable=readD)
    LabelD.grid(row=3,column=0, columnspan = 2)
    LabelD.config(anchor="w",background="#F1948A",justify="center",width="20",height="1",fg="black",
    cursor="hand2",font=("helvetica", "14", "bold"))

    LabelE=Label(miFrame, textvariable=readE)
    LabelE.grid(row=4,column=0, columnspan = 2)
    LabelE.config(anchor="w",background="#F1948A",justify="center",width="20",height="1",fg="black",
    cursor="hand2",font=("helvetica", "14", "bold"))

    LabelF=Label(miFrame, textvariable=readF)
    LabelF.grid(row=5,column=0, columnspan = 2)
    LabelF.config(anchor="w",background="#F1948A",justify="center",width="20",height="1",fg="black",
    cursor="hand2",font=("helvetica", "14", "bold"))

    LabelG=Label(miFrame, textvariable=readG)
    LabelG.grid(row=6,column=0, columnspan = 2)
    LabelG.config(anchor="w",background="#F1948A",justify="center",width="20",height="1",fg="black",
    cursor="hand2",font=("helvetica", "14", "bold"))  
# ---------------------------------Fin GUI ------------------------------------    
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: as I know `tkinter` is not `thread-safe` and new thread shouldn't change elements in GUI/Tkinter. It should use queue to send information to main thread and main thread should change GUI/Tkitner

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your problem might be that youre setting your StringVar straight to the thread your started.

According to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/_thread.html) page which explains the '_thread' module:

> _thread.start_new_thread(function, args[, kwargs])¶
>
> Start a new thread and return its identifier.

Which means that you are setting your string var to the returned value, which is the thread identifier.

On top of it, tkinter is not thread safe, and thus other threads that change the GUI may block the main thread (on which tkinter runs).

To fix your problem, I'd recommend the use of Queues in order to pass data to your main thread, and change the GUI elements from there.

You should also remove the lines of 'sets' you have that launch new threads.

Comment: I agree with you, but the application works perfectly if I send it as a normal script, instead of throwing it with a thread from the main application, thanks